# Coin toss: Smallest $n$ so that the given event is in $\mathcal{F_n}$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables that describe a sequence of coin tosses:

$\xi_n=\begin{cases}+1, & \mathrm{head}\\-1, & \mathrm{tail}\end{cases}$

Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be the $\sigma-$Algebra generated by $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots, \xi_n$

> I want to find the smallest $n$ so that the event is in $\mathcal{F_n}$ if such a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ exists.

a) A=Head appears for the first time after at most $10$ times tail.

b) B=Head appears at least once in the whole sequence.

c) C=The first $100$ tosses have the same result.

d) D=Head and tail don't appear more than twice respectively in the first 10 tosses.

My attempt

a) $11$

b) such a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ doesn't exist

c) $100$

d) This event is impossible, so it is in $\mathcal{F}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$

Comment: show your attempt

Comment: The question can be rephrased what is the fewest amount of times you have to flip the coin so that definitely know whether the said events have occurred or not occurred.

Comment: @clark I added my attempt, is it correct?

Comment: @user651021 looks good